# Capture return value from ado recordset

Tags: excel, stored-procedures, ado, vba

I am executing a stored procedure from Excel in this way:

```
Sub SPROCmain()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    conn.Open connString()
    conn.CommandTimeout = 0

    rs.ActiveConnection = conn
    rs.Open("EXECUTE [datamart].[dbo].[Pop_Main]")

    MsgBox t
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

It works just fine, dumps data into some tables for later usage.  is there a way for me to get the return value from the stored procedure here, or do I have to go the route where I set up a new `ADODB.Command`?

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly it all made sense...

```
Sub SPROCmain()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    conn.Open connString()
    conn.CommandTimeout = 0

    rs.ActiveConnection = conn
    rs.Open ("DECLARE @return_value int " _
           & "EXEC    @return_value = [datamart].[dbo].[Pop_Main] " _
           & "SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value")

    MsgBox rs.GetString

    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```